# Hadoop streaming subprocess can't find file

Tags: python, audio, hadoop-streaming

I have an hdfs directory that contains audio files. I wish to run fpcalc on each file using Hadoop streaming. I can do this locally no problem, but in hadoop fpcalc cannot see the files.
My code is:

```
import shlex
cli = './fpcalc -raw -length ' + str(sample_length) + ' ' + file_a
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cli_parts = shlex.split(cli)
fpcalc_cli = Popen(cli_parts, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
fpcalc_out,fpcalc_err=fpcalc_cli.communicate()
```

cli_parts is: ['./fpcalc', '-raw', '-length', '30', '/user/hduser/audio/input/flacOriginal1.flac'] and runs fine locally.

fpcalc_err is:

```
ERROR: couldn't open the file
ERROR: unable to calculate fingerprint for file /user/hduser/audio/input/flacOriginal1.flac, skipping
```

the file DOES exist:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/audio/input/flacOriginal1.flac
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    2710019 2014-08-08 11:49 /user/hduser/audio/input/flacOriginal1.flac
```

Can I point to a file like this in Hadoop streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work via:
1. Adding "-cacheFile hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/input/phone1/audio/flacOriginal1.flac#flacOriginal1" to my hadoop run command.
2. Referring to the file via the symlink i.e. as 'flacOriginal1'.